# Gradle + Sonar host URL and basic auth

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, build.gradle, sonarqube-scan

Have a Sonar instance running behind basic auth (not Sonar auth).

Using the Sonar Gradle plugin and specifying the Sonar host URL in `gradle.properties` via:

```
systemProp.sonar.host.url=https://admin:password@sonarqube.host.com
```

However this does not seem to authenticate as in Gradle logs I see:

> SonarQube server [https://admin:password@sonarqube.host.com] can not
>   be reached

If I curl the same URL I get a 200 response as expected.

Not sure why the `sonar.host.url` isn't playing nicely?

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- proxy authentication between SonarQube Scanner and Server is only
  supported since SonarQube 6.1
  ( [SONAR-8084](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8084) )
- with the above, `http.proxyUser` and `http.proxyPassword` are leveraged for basic proxy authentication (and you can leave `sonar.host.url` to the actual HTTP URL)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if my answer helps with the gradle plugin.

The maven plugin has the problem, that the first request does not use any credentials when calling `/batch/index` and I had to omit that route from basic auth. I think it's worth checking if that's the case here too.
Even using `user:password@server` was ignored completely by the plugin for the first call and I had no luck with `sonar.user`or any proxy user setup.

More details concerning my setup in my answer for the maven runner:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60132667/1838233