# How to access sonarqube if the server requires basic authentication?

Tags: maven, sonarqube

Our sonarqubeinstance deployed on a server which requires basic authentication. How we should configure sonar maven plugin in this case? Any combination of sonar.login and sonar.host.url (with or without user:password for server) will result in 401 error

Comment: Login to sonarqube server and [generate a token](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/user-token/). Then provide this token as value of `sonar.login` property. Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46114028/sonarqube-authorization-how-to-authorize-with-sonar-maven-plugin-when-sonar-fo?rq=1)

Comment: @leopal this results in 401 error

Answer (score 0):

The sonar-runner, even if configured with credentials, does not use these to make it's first call to the server. The endpoint is /batch/index. You have to allow public access to that endpoint. For all other urls basic auth is fine.

I have more details in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60132667/1838233